# How to check that an attribute not exists in an element with PHPUnit?

Tags: 8, testing

I'm trying to test that an element don't exists in a page. I know that exists the `elementAttributeExists()` method that checks that an attribute exists in an element. But I can't find any method like `elementAttributeNotExists()` to check that an attribute don't exists in an element.

So, with the following code I can check that the 'autocomplete' attribute is present in the #edit-pass element:

```
  public function testLoginForm() {
    // Going to the log in.
    $this->drupalGet('/user/login');

    // Checking that the autocomplete is not set.
    $this->assertSession()->elementAttributeExists('css', '#edit-pass', 'autocomplete');
  }
```

But how I can check that the autocomplete attribute is not present?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if there is a matching element for `#edit-pass` which has the attribute. Because `#edit-pass` targets only one element this has the same result when you know that this element exists:

```
$this->assertSession()->elementNotExists('css', '#edit-pass[autocomplete]');
```

Comment: I updated the code because with the space the code not works.